# Project Can Not Be Imported - SDK Doesn't Exist

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sdk

I have a solution which contains projects in .Net 4.8.

One of them is flagged as "(load failed").

The error I get when I try to reload the project is:

> The.Api.Shared.csproj
> : error  : The project file cannot be opened. Project "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props" was not
> imported by
> "The Api.Shared.csproj"
> at (0,0), due to the file not existing.

This project is in .Net 4.8, it has nothing to do with SDK 7.0.103.  Nothing in our solution deals with SDK 7, they are all 4.8 projects.

When I execute `dotnet --list-sdks` in PowerShell, it even shows this as installed:

[image: Powershell Output]

The .csproj is defined with:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Why is it mentioning the .Net SDK 7 in this case?

The strange this is it loaded and built this project without issue.  I closed Visual Studio, re-opened, and now it refuses to load the project.

**NOTE**: I've found a work-around for the moment.  If I go directly to the project file that won't load and double-click it in Explorer, it will open the entire solution in Visual Studio, including this project, without issue.  It's trying to open the SLN itself that refuses to load this project.

Comment: `dotnet --list-sdks` actually gives you a list of all installed SDKs on your system

Comment: @GiorgiAnakidze Hence why I mentioned I used it and have a screenshot of its results?  I'm not sure I'm following.